# How to install R-magic in jupyter-notebook?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I created a new environment in jupyter called "rpy2" and try to use `%%R` magic but the installation is failed.

QN: How to use %%R magic in jupyter-notebook ?

Platform: MacOS High Sierra

**Steps**

```
jupyter kernelspec list
conda create -n rpy2 python=3.7
source activate rpy2
which pip
/Users/poudel/miniconda3/envs/rpy2/bin/pip install rpy2
conda install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name rpy2 --display-name "Py37rpy2"
jupyter-notebook
```

**Issues**

```
# Now 
import rpy2 shows no error
import rpy2.rinterface  # gives error
```

**Note**

```
# I have checked all the files given in error log, all of them exist
  492  ls /Users/poudel/miniconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
  493  ls /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
  494  ls /Users/poudel/miniconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
  495  /Users/poudel/miniconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
  496  ls /Users/poudel/miniconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib

All shows given file, and none is missing.
```

**Error**

OSError: cannot load library '/Users/poudel/miniconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib': dlopen(/Users/poudel/miniconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib, 2): Symbol not found: _libiconv
      Referenced from: /Users/poudel/miniconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
      Expected in: /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
     in /Users/poudel/miniconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib

**Update**
As suggested by @akrun, I tried using `pyper` but it takes infinite time to load a libary and when stopped shows that it has broken pipe.

`pip install pyper`.

[image]

Comment: I think the `rpy2` is not installed properly.  I got similar issue in high sierra and then switched to `pyper`

Comment: @akrun can we use %%R  also using pyper?

Comment: It is slightly different, but the way I use works on jupyter

Comment: @akrun Just tried `pyper`, It works thanks.

Comment: @akrun How to install.package()  using this `pyper` ?

Comment: try `from pyper import *;  r=R(use_pandas=True); r("install.packages('<yourpackagename>')")`

Comment: But, I would prefer to do the instsallation etc coming from shell script that does all the checks and the pyper would be just communicating by loading the library etc.  The script can be sourced  I prefer to create a package and then get the output from calling the function.  Also, if you are running these jobs regularly, try to have a `miniCRAN` set up locally and install from it (to avoid any surprises)

Comment: @akrun Following this https://statcompute.wordpress.com/2012/11/29/another-way-to-access-r-from-python-pyper/     I installed library betareg in R-studio, and tried to use in jupyter-notebook . But the command  `r("library(betareg)")` takes forever to run. The cell keeps running infinite time. Have you experienced any problem like this? How to simply load a library in pyper?

Comment: I never experienced this.  I used to load multiple libraries.  can you try with a different library in case it is specific to this library (having lots of dependencies)

Answer (score 2):

if you're still looking for a solution, here's what you need.

Start the notebook with

> %load_ext rpy2.ipython

Then run R cells using the R magic function

> %%R
>
> library("tidyverse")

This works for the latest rpy2 version (3.4.5).